# ffmpeg: copy all audio streams and add two more

Tags: syntax, ffmpeg

I want to copy all audio streams from the input to the output. Additionally, I want to downmix two of the audio streams to stereo and add them. The output will be identical to the input but with two additional stereo tracks.

This is what I'm trying:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT 
    -map 0:0 -c:v copy /
    -map 0:1 -map 0:18 -af aformat=channel_layouts=stereo /
    -map 0:a -c:a copy 
OUTPUT.mkv
```

This is the error message.

```
Filtergraph 'aformat=channel_layouts=stereo' was defined for audio output stream 0:1 but codec copy was selected.
Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together
```

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: the input streams aren't mono, so go with

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT 
       -map 0:0 -c:v copy
       -map '[dm]' -map 0:a -c:a copy -c:a:0 aac
       -filter_complex "[0:1]pan=stereo[1a];[0:18]pan=stereo[18a];[1a][18a]amerge,pan=stereo[dm]" 
       OUTPUT.mkv
```

If you're on Windows, use `"[dm]"` Make sure you're using the most latest git build, rather than a release. Older versions have a bug in `pan` when no channel mappings are supplied, like in this revised command.

Comment: For some reason that failed with an out of memory error. It's running on an 8gb QNAP NAS with about 5gb spare.

ffmpeg version 4.0.2-static

Error while filtering: Cannot allocate memory
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:1
[libvorbis @ 0x69fcc40] 38 frames left in the queue on closing
....
Conversion failed!

Comment: That's suggesting that an audio stream in the input is corrupt.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no corruption in the input file. I ran a job that converted all of the input audio streams to stereo and copied the video. That ran through without problems. I've also been trying various other combinations, all of which use the same input file.

Comment: Of course I read it. I pasted the wrong file. Sorry about that.  This is the correct one. It's still failing. https://pastebin.com/VMac8Ran

Comment: I think this loses subs

Comment: Yes, add `-map 0:s? -c:s copy` to keep them.